# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php

Estos son los errores que muestra

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\wamp\www\ordencompra\update.php on line 22
>   ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\ordencompra\update.php on line 22

Este es el código:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';


    if($_POST)
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $emp_name = $_POST['emp_name'];
        $emp_descripcion = $_POST['emp_descripcion'];
        $emp_fecha = $_POST['emp_fecha'];
        $emp_cantidad = $_POST['emp_cantidad'];
        $emp_precio = $_POST['emp_precio'];


        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("
           UPDATE tbl_employees 
           SET emp_name=:en, 
               emp_fecha=:fe, 
               emp_cantidad:ca, 
               emp_precio:pr 
           WHERE emp_id=:id
        ");
        $stmt->bindParam(":en", $emp_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fe", $emp_fecha);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ca", $emp_cantidad);     
        $stmt->bindParam(":pr", $emp_precio);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Successfully updated";
        }
        else{
            echo "Query Problem";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: pudiera suceder que la cantidad de parámetros de tu consulta no coincide con la cantidad de columnas incluidas

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el resultado de hacer `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: "emp_precio:pr" ¿No debería ser emp_precio=:pr?

Answer (score 1):

En éste caso, te falta poner 2 símbolos de igual en tu sentencia

```
emp_cantidad:ca, emp_precio:pr
```

prueba cambiarlo a:

```
emp_cantidad=:ca, emp_precio=:pr
```

Comment: Si ese era el detalle. Muchisimas gracias